# Best practice for using Firebase Reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The function below is called to create a post

```js
const createPost = (newPost) => {
 app.database().ref('posts').push(newPost);
}
```

This is another version of the function

```js
const postRef = app.database().ref('posts');
const createPost = (newPost) => {
 postRef.push(newPost);
}
```

Which is **preferable** and **why**

Answer (score 1):

Both will add data to the database, but the second is better:

```
const postRef = app.database().ref('posts');
const createPost = (newPost) => {
 postRef.push(newPost);
}
```

Since `postRef` is referring to a root node in the database which you might use later in the js file.

Comment: I suspected that but I need more details as to why

Answer (score 0):

push returns a promise which resolves when the write to the database is complete. If you don't wait for it to resolve you will not know if it fails as your function will have returned successfully. Instead you will get an Unhandled rejection. Also, anything that runs after the functions has returned will receive less CPU and memory in firebase. So rewrite it like this:

```
const createPost = async (newPost) => {
    await app.database().ref('posts').push(newPost);
}
```

As to your original question you should not declare a variable if only used once, so I would opt for the first variation.

Comment: my concern with this approach is that `app.database().ref('posts')` is executed whenever the `createPost` function is called (**which can be many times**) as opposed to a resolved value contained in the variable `postRef`

Comment: That doesnt matter. app.database().ref('posts')  does not consume your backend.
It is the push method that consumes your backend